# Thread lock after opening new EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have a very weird error working with Spring JPA transactions. The thread is locked around 16 minutes and then continues without any problem.

Here is the situation:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class A {

    public String encrypt(String str){

        LOG.debug("encrypting...");

        // just data base read operations

    }

    public String encrypt(String str, String str2){

        // read and write database operations.

    }    

    public String foo(...){

        // read and write database operations.

    }

    public String bar(...){

        // read and write database operations.

    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class B {

    public String doSomething(...){

        LOG.debug("calling encrypt method...");

        String chain1 = this.a.encrypt("whatever");

        LOG.debug("calling encrypt method...");

        String chain2 = this.a.encrypt("again");

        LOG.debug("calling encrypt method...");

        String chain3 = this.a.encrypt("and again");

        ...
    }
}
```

Taking a look to the log file I see that it takes 16 minutes from log "calling encrypt method" to "encripting". So, have activated JTA logs and this is what I see:

```
15:09:04.317 DEBUG e.i.n.p.d.TipoMensajeDaoDelegate [45] - obteniendo mensaje para tipo operacion 0104 y protocolo 03
15:09:04.318 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [332] - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@4e6b01e9] for JPA transaction
15:09:04.319 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [471] - Participating in existing transaction
15:09:04.320 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [332] - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@4e6b01e9] for JPA transaction
15:09:04.321 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [471] - Participating in existing transaction
15:09:04.324 DEBUG e.i.n.c.p.p.b.B [485] - calling encrypt method...
15:09:04.325 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [332] - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@4e6b01e9] for JPA transaction
15:09:04.326 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [416] - Suspending current transaction, creating new transaction with name [es.indra.nnp.gestorclaves.GestorClavesServiceImpl.cifrar]
15:09:04.326 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [369] - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@27f2b012] for JPA transaction

...

15:24:29.954 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [408] - Not exposing JPA transaction [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@27f2b012] as JDBC transaction because JpaDialect [org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect@4d832b01] does not support JDBC Connection retrieval
15:24:29.955 DEBUG e.i.n.g.A [146] - encrypting
15:24:29.956 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [332] - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@27f2b012] for JPA transaction
15:24:29.957 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [471] - Participating in existing transaction
15:24:29.958 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [332] - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@27f2b012] for JPA transaction
15:24:29.958 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [471] - Participating in existing transaction
15:24:29.962 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [332] - Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@27f2b012] for JPA transaction
15:24:29.962 DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager [471] - Participating in existing transaction
...
```

Here, the facts:

- Error does not happen always, but when it does it is always in the same point.
- After 16 minutes more or less, the thread continues and calls the same method few times with no problem and finish correctly.
- When it happens, it is always around 15 minutes and 30 seconds.
- It happens with no concurrency. Anyway, when a thread is locked, if I start another thread there is no problem. The second thread is processed while the first is still locked.
- DDBB has being checked looking for database locks while the lock was happening. No database locks were found.
- Others methods form class A are called from others points of the code with no problem.
- Just happens on production environment. You can imagine how difficult is to do changes.
- Database connection is done via JNDI to MySql and application run in Tomcat.

I know that with this information is difficult to find out where the problem is. Just I hope someone can contribute with some thoughts that help me to find what is happening.

Comment: The problem was in the firewall. Making a few change in the connection configuration fixed it.

Comment: mind sharing what were the necessary config changes? you should post it as an actual answer

Answer (score 1):

For me this sounds pretty much like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736862/jpa-nested-transactions-and-locking).

Using REQUIRES_NEW will always ensure a new Transaction, so if there is an already existing one that should be suspended.

But since nested transactions are not supported by the [JPATransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html):

> On JDBC 3.0, this transaction manager supports nested transactions via
>   JDBC 3.0 Savepoints. The
>   AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(boolean)
>   "nestedTransactionAllowed"} flag defaults to "false", though, as
>   nested transactions will just apply to the JDBC Connection, not to the
>   JPA EntityManager and its cached objects. You can manually set the
>   flag to "true" if you want to use nested transactions for JDBC access
>   code which participates in JPA transactions (provided that your JDBC
>   driver supports Savepoints). Note that JPA itself does not support
>   nested transactions! Hence, do not expect JPA access code to
>   semantically participate in a nested transaction.

So the two transactions will share the same JDBC connection and there might be some locking involved. Is it that the transaction timeout is set to 15 minutes and that's why you see it hanging around for this amount of time?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. There is no transaction time-out defined, so we are working with the default value (-1). Also, think it can no explain why it does not happen always. I have to find out where the 16 come from, I think that is the key.

Comment: Does it replicate if instead of REQUIRED NEW you have REQUIRED?

Comment: I did not test it. We are working in a PCI-DSS production environment so it is really complicate to do changes. What I have done is remove transaction at class level and define it just in the methods it is needed. As "encrypt" method does not need transaction, let's hope we do not face the error again. Let's see. I will try to reproduce the error in other environment (if I am lucky) and test your idea.