# SpringBoot & nested transaction isolation level override

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

Spring boot, jdbc.

I feel a bit slippery when it comes to nested transaction..

Say there is MyService that uses MyRepository.

```
    @Named 
    @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED) // READ_COMMITTED < SERIALIZABLE
    class MyService {
      void do() {
        myRepository.add(entity);
         ...
      }
    }
    @Repository
    class MyRepository {
         @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
         void add(entity) {...}

    }
```

Say, in this case i want to make sure that MyRepository takes care about the add() method, making sure it set a maximum level lock `Isolation.SERIALIZABLE` over the table it deals with.

I do not want anyone to override it, since it would lead to concurrency issues.

(same applies to propagation level)

Question:

In case of nested transaction, will transaction's of `myService.do()` override Isolation level of `myRepository.add` and maker it less strict ?

What are the precautions when dealing with nested transactions?

Comment: Please follow [Nested transaction issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736862/jpa-nested-transactions-and-locking), i think it will answer your questions

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:
As per java docs of @Transactional annotation:

> The transaction isolation level. Defaults to Isolation.DEFAULT.
> Exclusively designed for use with Propagation.REQUIRED or
> Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW since it only applies to newly started
> transactions. Consider switching the "validateExistingTransactions"
> flag to "true"  on your transaction manager if you'd like isolation
> level declarations to get rejected when participating in an existing
> transaction with a different isolation level.